implementation of BAB strategy
I am implementing the Betting Against Beta strategy (Frazzini and Pedersen, 2014). I have some question
What I do:
- get historical data through yfinance
- calculate beta of each stock
- get 5 stocks with the largest betas and 5 stock with the lowest stocks (nothing magical with the number 5; it's just my choise)
- short the first group, and long the latter. Holding period is 1 month.
- deleverage the first ones (high-beta stocks), and leverage the low-beta stocks to 1.
Where I struggle is that some stocks can have a beta of 0.0015, for example, ie. very low number. So when I leverage to 1, I have to multiply it by a very large number, i.e., 1/0.0015. With this my returns and maximum drawdown get very large, absurdly large :)
I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm new to this but am eager to learn.
P.S. I understand that yfinance is not a perfect solution, and can have many data issues. Let's not discuss it now please. My problem is totally another issue.
Edit. This is how I estimate betas:
def calculate_stock_beta(stock_data, market_data):
try:
    stock_data['Return'] = stock_data['Adj Close'].pct_change()
    market_data['Return'] = market_data['Adj Close'].pct_change()
    merged_data = pd.merge(stock_data[['Return']], market_data[['Return']], left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('_stock', '_market')).dropna()
    if merged_data.empty:
        return None
    beta, alpha, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(merged_data['Return_market'], merged_data['Return_stock'])
    return beta
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error calculating beta: {e}")
    return None


You haven't told us how you calculate market beta?

I edited the question by adding the function for computing a beta. It's just a linear regression of stock returns on market returns.

I still don't know how you calculate market beta. Is it daily, weekly or monthly data? Over what horizon? You don't seem to use excess returns?

It's daily data based on a 1-year period. Data is from 2000-01-01 to 2004-03-31. But as I said when I calculate beta, I look at 1-year period. Let's, I'm at 2004-05-31, I take data from 2003-05-31 to 2004-05-31, and estimate stock betas based on this data. I use stock returns and ^GSPC returns. Not excess returns

A very low beta indicates that the asset's return is not correlated with the market and hence its volatility. I think there a re various ways to solve the weighting issue in this case. The most straightforward one is to give the weigths inversely proportional to the asset's vol. If you want to be more sophisticated, you can estimate the covariance matrix of the selected universe and apply a markowitz approach to create an optimal portfolio. My further advice for you is to estimate all the parameters in a rolling window. You can use RollingOLS class from statsmodels to estimate betas and a simple rolling std or cov for covariance-volatility. Good luck
